# Find the period of $y= 3\sin(8(x+4))+5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am doing a math problem for my homework and I know I got the answer wrong by looking at the back of the book. I am just trying to find out how to get that answer for future reference.

The question is to find the period of $y= 3\sin(8(x+4))+5$

My answer is $8$ but the book's answer is $\dfrac\pi4$.

Comment: Well, what is the period of $\sin(x)$? What about $\sin(2x)$ or even $\sin(8x)$?

Answer (score 1):

If you've had material on transformation of functions, you would have met "horizontal stretches/compressions" for  $ \ f(kx) \ $  , which takes the function  $ \ f(x) \ $ and "squeezes" it toward the  $ \ y$-axis if  $ \ k > 1 \ $  and "stretches" it away from the $ \ y$-axis  if  $ \ 0 < k < 1 \ $  .  Another way to think of this is that $ \ f(kx) \ $ says "plot the function $ \ f(x) \ \ k \ $ times 'faster' along the  $\ x$-axis" , when $ \ k > 1 \ $ ("squeeze it inward"); when  $ \ k \ $ is between  0 and 1 , write it as a fraction  $ \ k \ = \ \frac{1}{n} \ $ , so "plot $ \ f(x) \ \ n \ $ times slower" ("stretch it out").

For periodic functions, like the trig functions, this has the effect of changing the period for sine, cosine, secant, and cosecant to  $ \ T \ = \ \frac{2 \pi}{k} $  , and, for tangent and cotangent, to $ \ T \ = \ \frac{ \pi}{k} $ .  In your function, the multiplier  $ \ k \ $  is equal to 8  , so the period of this transformed sine function is  $ \ T \ = \ \frac{2 \pi}{8} \ = \ \frac{\pi}{4}$  .

The phase-shift of  -4  in the function  $ \ \sin( \ 8 \ ( x + 4 ) \ ) $ doesn't affect the period at all; it is only that multiplier 8 that matters.  Likewise, the "vertical stretch" of  3  and the "vertical shift" of +5 do not alter the new period.

Answer (score 0):

The period is calculated by asking when the argument inside the $\sin$ changes by $2\pi$. So if $p$ is the period, what you want to ask is when is $8([x+p]+4) = 2\pi + 8(x+4)$? Solve this for $p$ and your answer will agree with the book